# Return from parent method inside of Action<string>

Tags: c#, delegates

I am working inside of a method that performs a series of validation checks and should any of those checks fail it calls an `Action<string>` to run some common rejection code. The set up is something similar to this:

```
public void ValidationMethod() {
    Action<string> rejectionRoutine = (rejectionDescription) => {
        // do something with the reject description
        // other common code
    };

    if (condition != requiredValue) {
        rejectionRoutine("Condition check failed");
        // I currently have to put `return` here following every failed check
    }

    // many more checks following this
}
```

In this system once one check has failed validation I have no need to validate the rest, I just want to run the common rejection code inside the Action and exit the method. Currently to do this I just `return` on the next line following a call to `rejectionRoutine`. I'm wondering if there's a way I can incorporate the ability to return or terminate execution of the parent method from inside the `Action`?

I know this is a bit nit-picky but I feel like it is better for extensibility further down the road if someone else needs to add additional validation checks (they won't have to concern themselves with putting return all over the place) as well as encapsulating the common behavior of ending execution inside of code that is supposed to be common to these cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way of cleaning the code up a bit would be to extrapolate all of the checks out into a collection:

```
Dictionary<Func<bool>, string> checks = new Dictionary<Func<bool>, string>()
{
    {()=> condition != requiredValue, "Condition check failed"},
    {()=> otherCondition != otherRequiredValue, "Other condition check failed"},
    {()=> thirdCondition != thirdRequiredValue, "Third condition check failed"},
};
```

If it's important for the checks to be run in a particular order (this code has an unpredictable order) then you'd want to use something like a `List<Tuple<Func<bool>, string>>` instead.

```
var checks = new List<Tuple<Func<bool>, string>>()
{
    Tuple.Create<Func<bool>, string>(()=> condition != requiredValue
        , "Condition check failed"),
    Tuple.Create<Func<bool>, string>(()=> otherCondition != otherRequiredValue
        , "Other condition check failed"),
    Tuple.Create<Func<bool>, string>(()=> thirdCondition != thirdRequiredValue
        , "Third condition check failed"),
};
```

You can then use LINQ to do the validation:

```
var failedCheck = checks.FirstOrDefault(check => check.Item1());
if (failedCheck != null)
    rejectionRoutine(failedCheck.Item2);
```

Comment: Ahhh Servy, great minds think alike. I wrote code that was almost identical to this before I found a couple spots where it didn't make sense. There are some checks that will throw exceptions if they are evaluated when a previous check should have teriminated. Ie. check1 is value != null, check2 might do something with value assuming that it can't be null if we got this far

Comment: @JesseCarter Then, as I said at the end, you'll need to use a `List<Tuple<Func<bool>, string>>`.  It's only a tad more code.

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused about the way the bool in the Func will be evaluated? Is the actual evaluation of the bool value deferred until the Func is invoked? I assumed that it would be evaluated as soon as the Func was created

Comment: `Is the actual evaluation of the bool value deferred until the Func is invoked?`  Yes, it is.  `I assumed that it would be evaluated as soon as the Func was created.`  No, it will not.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize that it would behave this way, it is very good to know

Comment: Would a List<KeyValuePair<Func<bool>, string>> Be suitable as well as the Tuple or could it also potentially have an unpredictable order?

Comment: @JesseCarter You can use a `KeyValuePair`, but that class is specifically designed for use in a `Dictionary`.  It doesn't semantically represent the data here as it isn't really a key-value relationship between these two values.  While there is no technical reason not to use it, Tuple does a better job of representing this object.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, that makes sense. I'll implement this with a Tuple instead

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make any sense to return from the caller method inside a lambda expression.
(what if you call it after the method is finished running?)

Instead, you can change it to a `Func<string, Whatever>` and return its value:

```
return rejectionRoutine("Condition check failed");
```

Comment: The Action lives locally inside of the method so I don't see how it could be called if the method were finished running? If I returned something from a Func instead I would still have to do an if( returnValue == something ) return following every check. Or am I missing something with this approach?

Comment: @JesseCarter: Nothing prevents you from exposing the delegate outside the method.  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I edited the code example in my question, the Action only exists within the scope of the surrounding Validation method. I don't see how it could be called anywhere except for inside of that method.

Comment: Unfortunately with your new code example @SLaks solution won't work since the method doesn't have a return value.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to SLaks solution you can also throw an exception in your `rejectionRoutine` if your design allows it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think throwing an exception fits the current design. Thanks for the thought though

Comment: Exceptions shouldn't be used for normal control flow; they should be used for exceptional situations.

Comment: My thoughts exactly Servy and I'm sure that would be the consensus in my code review if I tried to do it that way

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "if your design allows it". It wasn't clear to me whether the condition your check might justify throwing an exception or not.